# How can I output the CNAME given by aws using terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform file that is using a `media_certificate` module

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "dumdum"

    workspaces {
      name = "stage_dummy"
    }
  }
}

module "media_certificate" {
  source = "../../../modules/media_certificate"
  domain = "media.dummy.com"
}
```

```
// media_certificate/main.tf

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "dumdum" {
  domain_name       = var.domain
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "dumdum" {
  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.dumdum.arn
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`

it gets stuck at this stage

```
module.media_certificate.aws_acm_certificate_validation.dumdum: Creating...
module.media_certificate.aws_acm_certificate_validation.dumdum: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
```

until it eventually fails after 45 minutes.

I understand that this is because the certificate is pending validation. Indeed to make it work I need to go on aws manually, grab the CNAME that they give me and set it on the DNS I use.

I tried using this

```
output "media_certificate_says" {
  value =  module.media_certificate.aws_acm_certificate.dumdum.domain_validation_options
}
```

However, when I run `terraform plan` I get this error

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 18, in output "media_certificate_says":
│   18:   value = module.media_certificate.aws_acm_certificate.dumdum.domain_validation_options
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.media_certificate is a object, known only after apply
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "aws_acm_certificate".
```

Any way to get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You should not have Terraform trying to finalize the certificate validation, by creating a `aws_acm_certificate_validation` resource, if Terraform isn't also creating those DNS records in your DNS provider.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The issue is that each new site that we spin up via terraform uses different DNS providers that we have little to no control over. Each client uses their own.

So we wanted to output the CNAME for quality-of-life purposes. So that we could copy it from the console and set it on whatever DNS our client is using

Comment: @ilrock I'm not sure why you think that's an issue. You just need to output the CNAME from the `aws_acm_certificate` resource. The `aws_acm_certificate_validation` resource doesn't actually create anything or give you any info you need in order to complete the process. The `aws_acm_certificate_validation` just causes Terraform to wait until the certificate validation process has completed. Since the validation process needs to be manual, you don't want to use that resource in your Terraform code.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm stuck on and the very reason I created this SO, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I can't find a way to output the CNAME. I added the output code I tried using to the question

Comment: Yeah, your question was really focusing on the wrong thing if that's where you are stuck now. You are trying to output a value from a module, but you first have to add that value to the module's outputs before you can do anything with it at a higher level in your Terraform code.